# Are beginner "design review" questions acceptable?

Tags: discussion, questions

This question on Stack Overflow was pointed out to me: [RTS Game AI Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6007108/rts-game-ai-thread)

The essence of the question is, I suspect, fairly basic, and certainly touches on [topics](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/651/tips-for-writing-the-main-game-loop) that have been [covered here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/2116/multi-threaded-game-engine-design-resources) before...

But he's taken the time to sketch out what he's trying to accomplish, and recognize that the architecture he's considering... may actually not be that great of an idea. IMHO, this is *great* - provided someone with some experience is willing to put the time in to analyze and comment on what is still very much a newbie question.

Provided they're reasonably well-though-out and written, is this something you would welcome here?

Comment: We do have an `architecture` tag..I assume that is what it is meant for :)

Answer (score 8):

I agree, that's the kind of question I'd enjoy answering here, and it's reasonably game development related.

Answer (score 5):

As long as they do some kind of research or effort, I don't have a problem with them.